# How can I access database mongodb on the server staging by console on the putty?

Tags: database, mongodb, remote-access, putty, ssh-keys

I want to access database mongodb on the server staging by putty. But i'm still confused to setting it

Look at this :

[image]

What needs to be set there?

I want a full explanation

Or maybe there is another better way to access mongodb?

Comment: Is there no one can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Putty you can create a SSH session on the server on which the MongoDB server is running, so you can't use Putty directly to connect to your MongoDB server. You can do the following:

## First Solution

1. Use SSH to connect to your server where the MongoDb is running (paste in your hostname or IP adress in the Putty Window and connect to Port 22)
2. Login with your server credentials on this server
3. Use `mongo` command line tool on the server and connect to the MongoDB server

## Second solution (therefore your MongoDB port has to be accessable from the internet and you need the `mongo` CLI tool on your machine)

1. Open a CMD on your Laptop/Desktop PC
2. Use `mongo yourMongoDbServerHostname:Port/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword` and you create a connection to your remote MongoDb server

If you are looking for a Mongo GUI client, have a look at: https://robomongo.org/ or https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

If thats not working, please provide further information about the MongoDb server.

Comment: I try you first solution. I input my ip public of staging server to input of hostname on the putty. I try open, there exist error like this : https://ibb.co/b1HZc6. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the process of making private and public key and how to use it. There may be a mistake in the process of making private and public key

Comment: I'm still confused to copy public key to server. After run this step : `1. Highlight entire public key within the PuTTY Key Generator and copy the text.`. I'm still confused to run the next step

Comment: Can you capture the process using video capture and upload it on youtube? And then share the link here. Maybe this will help me. Not only help me, but help others in need

Comment: this gos far beyond your original question. there are several youtube videos out there: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+ssh+on+server and a lot of good tutorials on the SSH topic.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot